# Add new rows to a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

After solve a problem with a loop that allow me extract images and test from a website, I'm having another problem, when I try to save the text that I extract in a new row in a csv file.

What I'm doing is search a div with the class "description", then I select the text that interest me, print the data (to check that everythings is correct) and finally use a **writerow** with the data extracted (previously I opened the file and add a row with the header).

**Edit:** my problem is that it's only saving one row, the last that the script have searched and extracted. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I'm going to put the two functions that I have in the script:

**main()** is where I have what I said before.

```
def main(url, destino):
    """ Acceso al sitio web """
    soup = bs(urlopen(url), 'lxml')
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    """ Acceso al archivo csv """
    fileName = 'datos/datos.csv'
    print fileName
    f = csv.writer(open(fileName, 'w'))
    f.writerow(["Lote", "Dato del lote", "Detalles"]) # Header

    """ Acceso a la descr. y escritura en el csv """
    description = soup.findAll(True, {'class':['description']})

    for text in description:
        loteNum = text.contents[1]
        loteDat = text.contents[3]
        detalle = text.contents[6]
        detalleE = detalle.encode("utf-8")
        print loteNum
        print loteDat
        print detalle
        f.writerow([loteNum, loteDat, detalleE])

    """ Descarga de las img. """
    for image in soup.findAll(True, {'class':['list_logo']}):
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        image_url = urlparse.urljoin(url, image['src'])
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        outpath = os.path.join(destino, filename)
        urlretrieve(image_url, outpath)
```

**getUrl()** allow me works in a determined range of images that I want to extract. I put here because I don't know if the problem could be something from this function.

```
def getUrl(opt, baseUrl):
    destino = "/home/ivanhercaz/monedasWiki/img"
    print "Instrucciones del script \n No te preocupes, no es complicado pero atiende a los pasos"
    print "Introduce 1 para obtener los archivos del 00001 al 00010"
    print "Introduce 2 para obtener los archivos del 00010 al 00099"
    print "Introduce 3 para obtener los archivos del 00100 al 00999"
    print "Introduce 4 para obtener los archivos del 01000 al 09999"
    print "Introduce 5 para obtener los archivos del 10000 al 19999"
    optSel = int(input(opt))
    # i es el rango
    # urlI es la transformacion de i en cadena
    # baseUrl es el enlace al sitio web de Pliego
    # url es la url completa con los parametros necesarios
    if optSel == 1:
        try:
            for i in range(0,10):
                r = str(0).zfill(4)
                urlI = str(i)
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, destino)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel == 2:
        try:
            for i in range(10,100):
                r = str(0).zfill(3)
                urlI = str(i)
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, destino)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel == 3:
        try:
            for i in range(100,1000):
                r = str(0).zfill(2)
                urlI = str(i)
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, destino)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel == 4:
        try:
            for i in range(1000,10000):
                r = str(0).zfill(1)
                urlI = str(i)
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, destino)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel == 2:
        try:
            for i in range(10000,18510):
                urlI = str(i)
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, destino)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel < 0:
        print "Valor inferior a 0"
    else:
        print "Algo ha salido mal"
```

Both functions are in the same file. If you could tell me what it's going wrong I'll be very thankful.

**Edit:** I have change the way to open and write the file like Moses Koledoye commented, but the script just write the last text checked yet. I think that the problem is something related with the loop to check and add the rows with the text, but I'm not finding the way to solve it. I share again the main().

```
<!-- language: python -->
def main(url, destino):
    """ Acceso al sitio web """
    soup = bs(urlopen(url), 'lxml')
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    """ Acceso al archivo csv """
    fileName = 'datos/datos.csv'
    print fileName

    """ Acceso a la descr. y escritura en el csv """
    description = soup.findAll(True, {'class':['description']})

    for text in description:
        loteNum = text.contents[1]
        loteDat = text.contents[3]
        detalle = text.contents[6]
        detalleE = detalle.encode("utf-8")
        print loteNum
        print loteDat
        print detalle
        header = ["Lote", "Dato del lote", "Detalles"]
        data = [loteNum, loteDat, detalleE]
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
            f = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            f.writerow(header)
            f.writerow(data)

    """ Descarga de las img. """
    for image in soup.findAll(True, {'class':['list_logo']}):
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        image_url = urlparse.urljoin(url, image['src'])
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        outpath = os.path.join(destino, filename)
        urlretrieve(image_url, outpath)
```

Comment: Can you give more the detail about the problem you're facing?

Comment: Sorry @MosesKoledoye! I thought that I said what it's doing wrong but I forgot it :/

Comment: I propose you use a `with open(...) as f` in your code and check that the code you posted has the same indentation with the one you have.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I use like you say `with open (...) as f` but it continues writting only the last text extracted. I think that I'm not passing correctly the parameters to extract and save from each url checked. But I'm not finding how I can do it.
I'm going to put how I write the **with open** in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for text in description:
    # ... some functionality
    data = [loteNum, loteDat, detalleE]
    with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
        f = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        f.writerow(header)
        f.writerow(data)
```

Every time you iterate over the `description` you open the file now in `w`rite mode, which will *overwrite* the previous contents.

You can either change it (the mode with which the file is opened) to `a`ppend, or just open the file to write to *outside of the loop*, like this:

```
with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    f = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    header = ["Lote", "Dato del lote", "Detalles"]
    f.writerow(header)
    for text in description:
        loteNum, loteDat, detalle = [text.contents[i] for i in (1, 3, 6)]
        detalleE = detalle.encode("utf-8")
        print loteNum, loteDat, detalle
        data = [loteNum, loteDat, detalleE]
        f.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Hi Oliver! Thank you for your answer. It works but it had a little fail that I could solve more easily. It write the header each time that wrote the data. I solve it calling the write header on the init function, so it creates that row only one time. Thank so much for your help!